# What is the name of the feature that as a card leaving behind the navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a feature that allows the user to swipe bottom to top a card to see more details about certain pinpoints. My question is how can I do such animation or how can I search in google such feature. I give some images below to give some context.

[image: Inital state of the card]

[image: Swiped state of the card]

Answer (score 2):

This is BottomSheet from google material https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-sheet-behavior/
It haves this behavior by default. You can find a lot of examples how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Android [**Bottom Sheet**](https://material.io/design/) component slides up from the bottom showing more relevant content. You can notice bottom sheets in apps like map apps (bottom sheet reveals location, directions information), music players (Play bar sticks to bottom and opens when swipe up). The bottom sheet is the component of android design support library.

In this article we are going to learn integrating a basic Bottom Sheet and types of bottom sheets. Before getting started refer Google material design guidelines about [**Bottom Sheet**](https://material.io/design/) for design specs.

[image]

You can archive this by **Bottom Sheet** : For more detail click on [link](https://material.io/design/)